# On what proper Gromov hyperbolic space does a free product act?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory

Per Bowditch, a group is relatively hyperbolic if it acts geometrically finitely on a proper geodesic Gromov hyperbolic space.
A free product of two (or finitely many) finitely generated groups is well known to be relatively hyperbolic. It also acts on an associated Bass-Serre tree which is however locally infinite.
My question: Is there a nice explicit description of a proper geodesic Gromov hyperbolic space on which the free product acts geometrically finitely?

Comment: So, how does the proof of relative hyperbolicity for free products work, if not by exhibiting an action?

Comment: In his paper "Relatively Hyperbolic Groups" Bowditch proved that relative hyperbolicity (with the above definition) is equivalent to admitting an action on a (locally infinite) hyperbolic graph K such that the following condition hold.
1) All edge stabilizers are finite.
2) The number of orbits of edges is finite.
3) The graph K is fine, that is, for every n ∈ N, any edge of K is contained
in finitely many circuits of length n. (Here circuit means a cycle without self–
intersections).

Comment: But I wanted a very explicit description of the action on a proper hyperbolic metric space. It feels like there should be some action on a finite valence tree lurking...

Comment: @ThiKu probably because in the *definition* of relative hyperbolicity, no properness (of the space) is required.

Comment: @ThiKu Also because it immediately follows from Farb's definition of relative hyperbolicity, which is known to be equivalent to Bowditch definition (which is approximately what Yellow Pig answered in his/her comment above).

Comment: @YellowPig, I think your intuition isn't right here.  A proper action on a finite-valence tree would imply that your group is virtually free.

Comment: @YCor What do you mean by 'no properness" is required ? In Farb or Osin's formulation, there is no properness indeed, you just ask that the coned-off graph is hyperbolic and that the BCP property is satisfied. However, in Bowditch definition, you need a geometricaly finite action on a **proper**, geodesic, hyperbolic metric space.

Comment: @HJRW But the action is not required to be proper, right ? It's required to be geometrically finite. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @M.Dus -- I thought that a geometrically finite action has to be proper; is that not the case?  Anyway, I'm pretty sceptical that there can be a geometrically finite action of a finitely generated group on a finite-valence tree unless the group is virtually free.

Comment: @HJRW Hum you're right I got confused. My bad. Also, maybe the OP might clarify what should be "some action on a finite tree lurking". Is it an actual action on a tree ? Is it an action somehow involving a tree ? For instance, is AGenevois answering your question ? I'm pretty sure the OP was aware of Groves and Manning's construction...

Comment: @M.Dus -- what makes you think that? I see nothing in their profile history which suggests they had already seen the Groves--Manning construction.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the characterisation of relatively hyperbolic groups given in Groves and Manning's article *Dehn filling in relatively hyperbolic groups* answers your question. I give a few details:

Let $G:=\underset{1 \leq i \leq n}{\ast} A_i$ be a free product of $n$ finitely generated groups. For every $1 \leq i \leq n$, fix a finite generating set $S_i$ of $A_i$. Clearly, $S:= \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n S_i$ is a finite generating set of $G$. The Cayley graph $\mathrm{Cayl}(G,S)$ is naturally a tree of spaces, the vertex-spaces being Cayley graphs of $A_i$'s. Now, the idea is to glue "horoballs" on the vertex-spaces. More precisely, consider
$$X:= \left( \mathrm{Cayl}(G,S) \cup \bigcup_\limits{g \in G} \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n \mathcal{H}(gA_i) \right) / \sim,$$
where the combinatorial horoball $\mathcal{H}(gA_i)$ over $\mathrm{Cayl}(A_i,S_i)$ is glued on $gA_i$.

The combinatorial horoball $\mathcal{H}(Y)$ over a graph $Y$ is defined as follows. The vertex-set of $\mathcal{H}(Y)$ is $Y \times \mathbb{N}$. If $u$ and $v$ are two adjacent vertices of $Y$, connect $(u,0)$ and $(v,0)$ with an edge. Also, for every $k \geq 0$ and for every vertex $u \in Y$, connect $(u,k)$ and $(u,k+1)$ with an edge. Finally, for every $k \geq 0$, if $u,v \in Y$ are two vertices satisfying $d_Y(u,v) \leq 2^k$, connect $(u,k)$ and $(v,k)$ with an edge.

It turns out that $X$ is a proper hyperbolic space, and $G$ naturally acts on it.

Comment: This is a nice answer, but I think the OP was hoping for another hyperbolic space whose description is well-known. Note that you can also glue ideal triangles rather than combinatorial horoballs, using Bowditch's construction.

Comment: Gluing horoballs is a pretty well known operation, going back pretty far into the history of Gromov hyperbolic spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. Here is another approach when the free factors are torsion-free abelian groups. Let $G=\mathbb{Z}^{d_1}*\mathbb{Z}^{d_2}...*\mathbb{Z}^{d_n}$. You can realize $G$ as a generalized Schottky group, acting on the real hyperbolic space $H^n$ for some $n$ via a geometrically finite action. You first take a geometrically finite kleinian group $G_0$ whose parabolic subgroups are exactly $\mathbb{Z}^{d_1}$,...,$\mathbb{Z}^{d_n}$. Now for each subgroup $\mathbb{Z}^{d_i}$, you choose some large $k_i$ and consider powers $e_1^{k_i},...,e_{d_i}^{k_i}$ of the standard generators $e_1$,...,$e_{d_i}$. If those $k_i$ are chosen sufficiently large, then an easy application of the ping-pong lemma shows that the subgroup $G_1$ generated by these elements is a free product.
Since the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^{d_i}$ generated by $e_1^{k_i}$,...,$e_{d_i}^{k_i}$ is still isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{d_i}$, $G_1$ is isomorphic to $G$.

Note that you can play the same game with torsion-free nilpotent groups, replacing the real hyperbolic plane by some simply connected Riemannian manifold of pinch negative curvature, but there are some differences. To simplify, assume that $G$ is of the form $G=G_1*\mathbb{Z}$, where $G_1$ is torsion-free nilpotent.
Then, $G_1$ can be realized as the stabilizer of a cusp in a finite volume manifold of pinched negative curvature. This is a consequence of several results, including those of P. Ontaneda's spectacular paper Pinched smooth hyperbolization, see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336869/finitely-generated-nilpotent-groups-as-cusp-groups) on mathoverflow for more details. You then choose a loxodromic element $g$ and applies the ping-pong lemma to $g$ and a subgroup of $G_1$ generated by elements that are far from the identity. You thus get a free product of the form $\mathbb{Z}*G_1'$. However, the main difference is that it is not clear to me if you can always have $G_1'$ isomorphic to $G_1$. To my knowledge, different lattices in the same nilpotent Lie group can be non-isomorphic, see for instance [there](http://maths.sogang.ac.kr/jlee/pdf-n/Aut_Heis.pdf).